# Datatable.js filtering issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datatables

I am using `datatable.js` on an `asp gridview`. Everything is working properly except for the column filters. When I filter with just the letter M my table shows & in the results because of `&amp`. I have tried searching for an answer and have had no luck. How would I perform the filtering and ignore `&amp` in my columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing additional research I was able to get a working solution to my problem.

```
var stripReserved = function (a) {
    return a.replace('&amp;', "&");
}



$("#someTable").dataTable({
"aoColumns":  [

        'mData': function(source, type, val){
            if (type === 'set') {
            source.value = val;
            source.value_display = val;
            source.value_filter  = val=="" ? "" : stripReserved(val);
            return;
        }
        else if (type === 'display') {
          return source.value_display;
        }
        else if (type === 'filter') {
          return source.value_filter;
        }

        return source.value;
    }]
});
```

I found the solution at the following link and adjusted it to work with my problem.
http://questiontrack.com/how-to-search-only-text-in-jquery-datatables-1107212.html